# How to speed up data retrieval from sqlite in iPhone app

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have 10000 records in my sqlite table. It takes over 3 minutes to load into array. How can i speed up the process. Is there any way i can reduce time to half atleast?

My code :

```
NSString *qry=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from employees"];
    const char *sql=(char *)[qry UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt,NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        Vertex *objVertex = [[Vertex alloc] init];
        int counterIndex=0;
         while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW){
            objVertex.vid=sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
            objVertex.lat=sqlite3_column_double(selectstmt, 1);
            objVertex.lon=sqlite3_column_double(selectstmt, 2);
            objVertex.alt=sqlite3_column_double(selectstmt, 3);
            objVertex.assoc_type=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 4)];
            objVertex.assoc_id=sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 5);
            objVertex.link=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 6)];
            objVertex.bf=sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 7);
            
             [appdel.dicVertexEntry setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",counterIndex] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",objVertex.vid]];
             // do pass vertex to Algo
             counterIndex++;
        
        }
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:appdel.dicVertexEntry forKey:@"VertexData"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to supply more information to your problem, such as what data are you getting from your sqlite table, how are you retrieving it and so on.

Comment: Without knowing much of your application: > I have 10000 records in my sqlite table. It takes over 3 minutes to
> load into array. 1)Is the user able to see the 10000 records? 2)Do you really need to load 10000 records in memory for what you want to achieve? Sometimes the problem is not related to the technical aspect of the question, but with the question itself.

Comment: We have one simple employee table (12000 entries) with fields e_id, name, salary, dob, joining date and age.

Comment: Yes i want all records on launch of app.

Comment: Can you state the purpose? I am asking this to try to give you a solution.

Comment: I have to create shortest path based on vertex and edges table for that i am using dijkstra alog. For that i need to map vertices and edges data. I cannot load them into parts. My current code mentioned above takes over 3 minutes to load 12000 vertex and more 4 minutes for 13000 edges.

Comment: put prepolated coredata db into the bundle. then use it.

Comment: do you have any tutorial on this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try explicitly specifying the field names you require in the SQL Statement rather than just using *, that should give you a minor performance increase.  Have you considered using Core Data rather than sqlite direct?

Answer (score 0):

Better solution will be if you fetch starting 100 or some fixed number of records and on scrolling fetch next 100. This will speed you up.

To optimized query you can fetch only required fields from query rather then All using *.

Comment: Another thing you can add all records to NSMutableArray and save to NSUserDefault in one go rather than once by one and Sync It.